# Jquery Datepicker not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In the below code i have a jquery datepicker.I tried to implement in bootstrap modal .But it is not working .Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id$=txtdob]").datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif'
            });
        });
    </script>


 <input type="text" style="width:30%" id="txtdob"  name="nmdob"  class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Dob"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function in the body onload() because on bootstrap, the elements are not initialized yet, so you cannot access the DOM.

Comment: I am using master page so can i call on window onload

Comment: Can you change your master page such that the `<body>` element contains the `onload="init();"` attribute? Then call your function `init()`.

Comment: I am working on application which refer to master page so i could not remove master page is there any other possibility

Comment: Not remove, edit the master page which you are using.

Comment: I called on loading but issue not fixed

Comment: What happens if you additionally change the [id$=txtdob] to #txtdob as suggested below?

Comment: I tried but no solution .The thing is it works outside modal popup but not inside popup

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$("[id$=txtdob]").datepicker({
```

to

```
$("#txtdob").datepicker({
```

and put it in `$(document).ready...`

Comment: i tried but no solution.It works outside modal popup but  not inside modal popup

Comment: Please elaborate *why* this would solve the question and edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: It seams that I make mistake. Did not see that you already have $(function () {}; which is same as $(document).ready();
Can you post jsfiddle? Thanks